# Issue with using the system-command

Tags: matlab

when I use in a terminal session

```
curl -help
```

I get the help list. When I use in MATLAB

```
system ('curl -help')
```

I get the error:

> System Lookup error, curl : undefined symbol:curl_url_cleanup. Linux is Fedora based Solus 4.0

In my understanding the system command should work like this. How can I get the help file?

Comment: Thanks perfect. Worked at once.

Comment: Awesome! I've turned my comment in an actual answer then.

Comment: yes, env -i was the missing point. I can now skip all my Windows installation and move to Linux. No more Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB modifies the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, so that its own libraries can be found. However, MATLAB comes with tons of external libraries, and usually these are older versions.

So it happens at times that a command executed through `system` links to a version of a library that comes with MATLAB, rather than the one that comes with the OS.

The solution is to execute the command in a "clean environment", such as the one provided by `env -i`:

```matlab
system('env -i curl -help')
```